# Finding total Sum of memory utilization in Windows using NEt:SNMP

Tags: windows, perl, snmp, net-snmp

Well , i have digged out individual OIDs for the process and i am able to get the memory usuage for each of them , but the issue is how do i get the total process usuage. 
The problem is the OID for individual process usuage is  1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1.2.X
Now X can be any number used to identify the process and adding more difficulty to it , 
its not in sequence. For example, 
I can have OIDs in the following order

1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1.1.1 = INTEGER: 971526993
1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1.1.4 = INTEGER: 3562884
1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1.1.296 = INTEGER: 496
1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1.1.340 = INTEGER: 12804
1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1.1.344 = INTEGER: 68178
1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1.1.348 = INTEGER: 40
1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1.1.372 = INTEGER: 3535
1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1.1.424 = INTEGER: 3985009
1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1.1.436 = INTEGER: 27875212
1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1.1.440 = INTEGER: 72218
1.3.6.1.2.1.25.5.1.1.1.592 = INTEGER: 4820

---

---

and so on . . .

Currently my perl script is something like this :

```
      my ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(
           -hostname  => shift || 'hostname',
              -community => shift || 'public',
      );

      if (!defined $session) {
                 printf "ERROR: %s.\n", $error;
                    exit 1;
            }
      //$OId_number will hold the OId of the particular process       
      my $result = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => [ $OID_number ],);

      if (!defined $result) {
                       printf "ERROR: %s.\n", $session->error();
                          $session->close();
                             exit 1;
       }

       printf "The Memory allocated  for process is  '%s' is %s.\n",
       $session->hostname(), $result->{$OID_number};
       $session->close();
       exit 0;
```

Comment: The question is how do i get the complete memory used for a given system.  As u can see the range of the X (last number in the OID) ranges from 1 - 7500. If i keep iterating and then check for genuine OIDs , it takes about 20min to get the total memory utilization. I cannot afford to waste so much of time :(  , is there any faster way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Net::SNMP's get_bulk_request](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aSNMP#get_bulk_request%28%29_-_send_a_SNMP_get-bulk-request_to_the_remote_agent)? You should get all data at one request.